# how to add commons.io to class path?

Tags: jsp, tomcat

I am working on this JSP project and I had to use FileUtils class from apache.common.io library. I have already downloaded the jar file for commons.io but still need to specify the class path, but I still don't know what class path, since I am working with jsp files.I have used jar files on eclipse before when I wrote actual java classes, but this is a little different.. anyone got a hint?

Answer (score 2):

1. Your project have a `WEB-INF/lib` folder (otherwise create it manually inside the project), paste it there. It will be applicable for only this particular application.
2. You can paste the jar file in your `JRE_HOME/lib/ext` also. It will be applicable for all the applications in your system.
3. You can load the jar file only for all the applications running on the Tomcat by pasting it inside `CATALINA_HOME/common/lib` (in case of Tomcat 5.5) or `CATALINA_HOME/lib` (in case of Tomcat 6)

In all circumstances you need to restart the tomcat to get it loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Put jar file into your web app's WEB-INF/lib folder. 
Put the following line at the top of your JSP.

```
<%@ page import="org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils" %>
```